# How to get the same IDs those have all value of another table using SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

### Table one called PublisherSupply

```
| Publisher | Book |  
| ------------------------|  
| A | Pride and Prejudice |  
| B | 1984 |  
| B | The Great Gatsby |  
| B | Pride and Prejudice |  
| C | 1984 |  
| C | The Great Gatsby |  
| D | Beloved |  
| D | 1984 |  
| D | The Great Gatsby |  
| E | Beloved |  
| E | 1984 |  
| E | The Great Gatsby |  
| E | Sense and Sensibility |
```

### Table two called Orders

```
| Orders |  
| ---------------- |  
| Beloved |  
| The Great Gatsby |  
| 1984 |
```

Now I want to find all Publishers who published all books in the orders list.
Namely `D and E`

Comment: Publisher E doesn't have Order "Sense and Sensibility" book..  How this will be a answer?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the RIGHT JOIN as only the publishers whose books are mentioned in the orders table are required to be displayed.

```
SELECT a.publisher
    FROM publishersupply a RIGHT JOIN orders b 
    ON a.book=b.book
    WHERE a.publisher IN ('D','E')
    GROUP BY a.publisher,a.book,b.book;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method, using `join`, `group by`, and `having`:

```
select p.publisher
from publisher p join
     orders o
     on p.book = o.book
group by p.publisher
having count(*) = (select count(*) from orders o);
```